# JQuery: Find all id in a page matching with the given pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have set of html elements (dynamic elements) out of which one element is a template.. Now I want to find all the id's in the page except template

Ex:

```
<div id="text[1]"></div>
<div id="text[2]"></div>
<div id="text[XXX]"></div>
```

Below Jquery function will give me all three elements, but I want div elements with id's test[1] and test[2] and not test[XXX].. How can we use regex here..?

```
$("div[id^='test']")
```

Comment: This regex selector is wonderful https://j11y.io/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your contributions.. Below code worked for me..

```
$("div[id^='text']:not([id$='XXX\]'");
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) filter

```js
$("div[id^='text']").not('[id*=XXX]').css('color','red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text[1]">text[1]</div>
<div id="text[2]">text[2]</div>
<div id="text[XXX]">text[XXX]</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might not need jQuery for that

```js
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('div'))
  .filter(el => el.id.match(/your regex here/))
  .forEach(el => console.log(el.id));
```

```html
<div id="text[1]"></div>
<div id="text[2]"></div>
<div id="text[XXX]"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return all the Divs you need.

```js
$('div')
    .filter(function() {
        return this.id.match('text\\[.\\]');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text[1]"></div>
<div id="text[2]"></div>
<div id="text[XXX]"></div>
```